# React value changed

Tags: knockout.js, kolite

Lets say I have `name = ko.observable('John')` that is bind to the `input` as value. I need to show (hidden before) `<button>Save</button>` if `name` get changed. So if I edit name from `John` to `Jack` then save button should appear and if edit back to `John` it should hide again. Have you any ideas of what kind of binding/extension can be applied here?
Great thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called dirty tracking.

There is a ko plugin called [KoLite](https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite) which contains a dirty flag implementation (you can read about how it works in [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)):

The usage is very simple you just need to pass your obserables into the `ko.DirtyFlag` (this will return computed observable) method:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable('John');
    self.dirtyFlag = new ko.DirtyFlag(self.name);
}
```

And in your view you can bind to the `isDirty` property on your `dirtyFlag`:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
<div data-bind="if: dirtyFlag().isDirty">
    <button>Save</button>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/6dz7g/)